# How to insert a word add in from another add in

Tags: ms-word, office-js, word-addins

is there a way to add a word add in to the document out of another word add in?

Probably there's a way to add via editing the Custom XML or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great idea, however this is not possible today. Make sure to vote for an existing request or add a new one in our UserVoice Channel. https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/163566-add-in-word